# How to use jCrop and Image Intervention?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this fiddle where i crop image and get values such as `x,y,x1,y1,w,h`:

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/2511

Now what i want is to save that image with those values with Image Intervention but i dont know what function i need to use to pass those parameters. Any suggesion?

```
 function updateCoords(c)
  {
    console.log(c);
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#x2').val(c.x2);
    $('#y2').val(c.y2);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
  };
```

I tried like this but is say that first arguement must be integer.

```
   Image::make($image->getRealPath())->crop($w,$h,$w,$h)->save($path. '/' .$filename); but i get an error that crop first argument need to be integer.
```

Also what i try is this but it save full size image:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())
   ->rectangle($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2)->save($path. '/' .$filename);
```

I used rectangle because only that function recives 4 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

http://image.intervention.io/api/crop

### http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/10207/

I think this should do the trick.

```
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'));

$crop_box_start_x = intval($request->get('x'));
$crop_box_start_y = intval($request->get('y'));

$crop_box_width = intval($request->get('h'));
$crop_box_height = intval($request->get('w'));

$image = $image->crop($crop_box_width, $crop_box_height, $crop_box_start_x, $crop_box_start_y);

$image->save('path/to/save.png');
```

**Tip:** Just apply validation before cropping that the area you're cropping is inside the image.

Comment: i use r code but image is bigger then what i select ... how can i fix that?

Comment: its smaller but still really big

Comment: maybe i need to get y =y2-y1 ??

Comment: nope you dont need to do y2 - y1, the code is fine.. just make sure values at crop are the same as values at server

Comment: i checked and they are the same

Comment: Code updated, sorry my bad, i hope now your problem would be fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135004/discussion-between-rummykhan-and-uzhas).

Comment: thats it ...tnx a lot :)))

Comment: Hi, i would like to see the solution, since the above solution is not working for me either.